# how create bacgroundColor animation for UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c

I create UIView for Section and once for Row. Then i create method:

```
-(void)startBlinking {
   [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
   [UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^
   {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^
       {
           [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
       } completion: NULL];
   }];
}
```

But if i call this method i not view any animations. background color change very fast without animation... :(( WTF??

i need create blink background color effect for sections and rows if catch events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`backgroundColor` transitions are not animatable.  I would suggest you add a subview to your cell with an `subview.alpha = 0.0f` and then in the animation block you can transition the alpha to `1.0`.  This will get you the desired effect.

Comment: Cool. Just make sure that your `subview` can handle device rotation (resizes itself properly)